# How to Divide to values in a SQL-question Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i make a fifth column that divides the values i get from Vikt and AntalOrder?

```
/*

*/
select O08T1.pickdate,
          O08T1.divcode,
sum(O08T1.calcwght) as Vikt,
sum(O08T1.calcvol) as Volym,
count(O08T1.ordno) as AntalOrder

from O08T1  
group by O08T1.pickdate, O08T1.divcode
order by Pickdate DESC
```

Comment: Hav you tried:  `sum(O08T1.calcwght) / count(O08T1.ordno)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use explicit division, I am guessing that `ordno` is never `NULL`.  If so, you can phrase the query as:

```
select O08T1.pickdate, O08T1.divcode,
       sum(O08T1.calcwght) as Vikt, sum(O08T1.calcvol) as Volym,
       count(*) as AntalOrder,
       avg(O08T1.calcwght) as avg_vikt
from O08T1  
group by O08T1.pickdate, O08T1.divcode
order by Pickdate DESC
```

Comment: When i use this i get the following Error, and when i remove avg(O08T1.calcwght) as avg_vikt it works as it did before. Error when executing Sql
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
--> Error at offset: 159

Comment: Just a typo, missing comma after AntalOrder. Now corrected.

Comment: In this table pickdate comes with timestamp, is there a way where i can select the date without the timestamps in it?